# Heroku deployed , Application error 'engines.node (package.json): unspecified'

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-deployment

I made the react app and deployed with Heroku but when I click the app link, it shows  Application error.

What I did, I made the `Procfile` this is working, add `engine : node version` in `package.json` this is not working.

I guess the `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL = error`  this cures the problem, but I have no idea what to do.

I didn't used express.. Only pure, simple react app.

This is the Build Log

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       audited 2311 packages in 16.151s
       
       158 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > my-cv@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_2c7b70c1
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled successfully.
       
       File sizes after gzip:
       
         478.37 KB  build/static/js/2.80a0e7e2.chunk.js
         29.13 KB   build/static/css/2.b6d59024.chunk.css
         3.59 KB    build/static/js/main.6015e25f.chunk.js
         773 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.cd2e31bd.js
         316 B      build/static/css/main.59a22ca6.chunk.css
       
       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       
       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:
       
         npm install -g serve
         serve -s build
       
       Find out more about deployment here:
       
         https://cra.link/deployment
       
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 2311 packages in 16.924s
       
       158 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 146.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "i18next": "^20.3.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "plotly.js": "^2.2.1",
    "plotly.js-basic-dist": "^2.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You indeed don't seem to have any engines specified in your package file, so what's your _question_?

Comment: My app keeps getting application error, whether I added  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.1",
    "npm": "6.14.8"
  }, on my package.json or not. Can you advise how solve this problem.

Comment: Now my app is working! After setting the build!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the NPM and NODE version as engine.

Here is what you need to add:

```
"engines": {
        "node": "14.x",
        "npm": "6.x"
    }
```

Your package.json code should look like:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
 "engines": {
            "node": "14.x",
            "npm": "6.x"
        },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "i18next": "^20.3.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "plotly.js": "^2.2.1",
    "plotly.js-basic-dist": "^2.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

### Note:

The node and npm verion may be different in your case. You should write `npm --version` to get the version of npm likewise type `node --version` to get the verion of node. Then add it here, you may just write 14.x no need to write 14.2.2 (it is just an example)

Don't forget to close your code ide, and restart everything. Create a new build and then upload.

Mostly the procfile looks like: `web:node server.js`

Here server.js is the file that starts the server.

Comment: Thank you for your attentive reply! I just did what you told me, but it doesn't work..

Comment: after I added engine, heroku logo shows  `Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.15.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.8
       
       Resolving node version 14.15.1...
       Downloading and installing node 14.15.1...
       npm 6.14.8 already installed with node`

Comment: After installed buildpack and procfile : web: bin/boot , now my app is working Thanks!